# show the location of each occurence of the character 'e' in a string

Tags: javascript, string, loops, character

**WORKED UP AN ANSWER. SCROLL TO BOTTTOM**

I'm having trouble trying to display this character. For the most part, I have the code structure set but I'm having trouble storing the correct values in the arrays. Getting stuck and burned out!

```
wordString = 'i, always, have, fruit, for, breakfast, consisting, of, a, small, fruit, bowl, with, yogurt, on, top, of, the, fruit, but, if, it, is, doughnuts, I, always, have, two, sometimes, they, have, sprinkles, and, sometimes, not, i, never, have, cereal, or, eggs, this, breakfast, regimen, is, very, healthy, especially, the, doughnuts.';
var wordPosition = [];

var letterAppearance = wordString.match(/e/g);

var positionStart = 0;

for(i = 0; i <= letterAppearance.length; i++) {

    positionStart = wordPosition[i];

    if(positionStart === 0) {
        positionString = wordString.substr(positionStart, wordString.length)
    } else {
        positionString = wordString.substr(wordPosition[i], wordString.length)
    }

    wordPosition[i] = positionString.indexOf('e');

}
```

Thanks for the help ahead of time

***EDIT***

Okay so I've worked on this a bit more and have something a bit simpler but have not yet gotten it to work. My values are not quite correct other than the 1st couple in the array

```
var wordPosition = [];
var letterAppearance = wordString.match(/e/g);
var positionStart = 0;

for( i = 0; i <= letterAppearance.length; i++){

wordPosition[i] = wordString.indexOf('e')+ positionStart;
positionStart = wordPosition[i];
}
```

Heres are the values that I get.

14,28,42,56,70,84,98,112,126,140,154,168,182,196,210,224,238,252,266,280,294,308,322,336,350,364

**EDIT ANSWER FOUND**

Okay, after working on it some more I've gotten the correct code for the answer. Here it is in the simplest form.

```
locations = " letter 'e' occurs at locations: ";
for (i = 0; i <= wordString.length; i++){
    character = wordString.substr(i,1);
    if(character === 'e'){
        locations = locations + i.toString() + ",";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after working on it more, I've found the answer in it's simplest form.

```
locations = " letter 'e' occurs at locations: ";
for (i = 0; i <= wordString.length; i++){
    character = wordString.substr(i,1);
    if(character === 'e'){
        locations = locations + i.toString() + ",";
    }
}
```

Here is the output. 
letter 'e' occurs at locations: 14,31,108,160,171,175,181,188,198,210,214,227,229,236,240,242,251,265,275,279,288,294,302,305,316,

Answer (score 0):

I think that's too complicated to search for just some 'e' positions. You can try this:

```
for (int i=0; i < /*string lenght*/ ; i++)

    if (/*String char at i*/ == 'e')
        /*Store position */
```

Comment: Giving that a try right now. I feel like there is something wrong with this though because I haven't gotten it to display correctly yet. This is what I have so far
    var wordPosition = [];

    for(int i=0; i < wordString.length ; i++){
 if(wordString.indexOf(i) === 'e'){
  wordPosition[i] = wordString.indexOf(i);

 }
}

Comment: The problem there is that you are saving it like that:  "e found un pos 4" -> wordPosition[4] = 'e'. From what I understood, please tell if Im wrong, If you find the first e in position 4, you want this to happen: wordPosition[0] =  4. If you find a second 'e' in position 11, then: wordPosition[1] = 11, and so on... . So, inside the for you should add another counter. Forma example: var wordPosition[]; for (int i=0, j=0; i<wordString.lenght; i++) { if (wordString.indexOf(i) == 'e') { wordPosition[j] = i; j++; } }

Comment: I dont really know which program language you re using but that should work 99% sure. Anyway, your wordPosition[] havent got a fixed size, maybe there is a problemas there, as I said it will depend on the language

Comment: My knowledge about Javascript is 0. But being curious. I can see your edit there, and what's wrong with the result ? To my mind that's correct, what is the result your expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var str = "scissors";
var indices = [];
for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
    if (str[i] === "s") indices.push(i+1);
}
```